# Installing RXTX serial drivers onto OSX and implementing path into Netbeans

Tags: java, macos, netbeans, rxtx

I took a bunch of floppy drives and hooked them up to an Arduino to make it play music. Through the steppers motors, etc.

I'm running a custom Arduino script called Moppy which is run through the Netbeans IDE. It basically controls and sends signals to the FDD's. It requires a RXTX serial driver in order to communicate with the Arduino/FDD's.

I used these instructions to try to install the RXTX driver:

> Open a Terminal window (found under Application->Utilities) and type:
>   `$ cd Desktop (or the folder where you downloaded the script) $ sudo sh ./fixperm-217-leo.sh Password: <your administrator password>`

I had the script on the desktop, and terminal said the command wasn't found.

So then I tried these instructions from the actual RXTX website:
http://rxtx.qbang.org/wiki/index.php/Installation_on_MacOS_X[1]

I tried entering `sh ./configure` and the command wasn't found. I installed xcode like it said but I don't know if it did anything.

**Basically, how to I install the RXTX serial driver onto OSX in the Java folder, and what path do I put into the VM option box in Netbeans for the program I'm running?**

Comment: Try posting this in the Arudio stackexchange for a more specific audience: http://arduino.stackexchange.com/